# What's filter needed when covert gif to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using below command to convert gif to mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i test.gif -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -y  output.mp4
```

I know there are many filters in FFmpeg but which filters are need here?

I think `scale` is needed.

## EDIT

I am sorry that I have not made my question clear.

In fact, I wan to only configure specific filters when I build ffmpeg. So I want to know when convert gif to mp4, which filters are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIFs are decoded as RGBA so `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is needed for a web-compatible MP4.

If the GIF has even dimensions, you can skip `scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2`, but if you don't know, it's safer to keep it.

---

For running the given command, libswscale is needed and the scale and format filters. Format is automatically selected.

Comment: I want to know `ffmpeg -r new_fps` should use which filters? I already use `fps` filter but it can not work.

Comment: The `-r` option is not a filter; it's implemented in core ffmpeg code.

Comment: However it reports `[AVFilterGraph @ 0xd4cc5580] No such filter: 'null'`.

Comment: It's best to always select these filters: `crop,format,hflip,null,select,transpose,trim,vflip`